# Tokens: App and User Tokens

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, token

I am just starting out looking at Facebook applications. I am planning to make an app – where should post photos to users walls or photo albums. It happens typically days after they have installed the app.

I have read that there exists different tokens. User tokens which expires after some time and App tokens, which does not expire. I have made some experiments – and must admit I am a bit confused. I tried getting tokens for 2 different users. The user tokens were different (of course). However, the App tokens was not? My questions are.

- Is the App token always the same for all users?
- Must I also get a user token from a user of my app when I have an App token?

EDIT:
Since I posted this yesterday – I have realized that I need to make my questions clearer.

- Is the App Token only to be used with access to information about the
  application itself – or is it e.g. used to achieve a non-expiring
  possibility to post to a user’s own wall?
- If I want to be able to post a photo to a users wall long after he
  has been using my app last. Should I when use an App Token or a User
  Token?

Answer (score 0):

> User Token

Normal user access token expires in 2 hours. But you can extend this to 2 months. [See here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#step1)

> App Access Token

Private to the admin of the app, don't public it. Also it never expires. Generally, its not required in app development (just for some APIs). You can get it from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)

There's a `page access token` too for managing the pages.

You must go through this once: [Access Tokens and Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)

Comment: Hi. Read it a couple of times now. Have I understood it correct: Can my app publish a photo to a users wall if my app has got an App Token? Or what does it require?

Comment: you need to set the permission: `upload_photos`. 
If the answer helped you , you can mark it as the correct.